# MUMPS Address Validation

Tags: intersystems-cache, mumps

I am working on prerequisite questions for a class I am trying to attend. I am working on revisions to two pieces of code. I have completed one and I am stuck on this one. I am trying to read an abbreviated address line. In this case FL33606. I am able to read the address. But I am receiving an undefined error for the Quit command "Q: done". Would someone be able to assist me in identifying what is wrong?

```
N prompt,val, done
    S prompt="Enter State and Zip (StateZip): "
    F  W !,prompt R val Q:val=""  D  Q:done  
    . I val'="?2A5N" W !,"Invalid entry" Q
    . S done=1
    I val="" q
    W !,"Valid Entry: ",val
    Q
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two errors

- `done` variable should be defined before the first read
- the pattern should not be in quotes, where `?` is the operator not `=`

```
  S prompt="Enter State and Zip (StateZip): "
  S done=0
  F  W !,prompt R val Q:val=""  D  Q:done  
  . I val'?2A5N W !,"Invalid entry" Q
  . S done=1
  I val="" q
  W !,"Valid Entry: ",val
  Q
```

Why do you use short commands, and dots?

Is not this much better readable?

```
  Set prompt = "Enter State and Zip (StateZip): "
  For {
    Write !,prompt 
    Read val 
    Quit:val=""  
    Quit:val?2A5N
    Write !,"Invalid entry" 
  } 
  If val="" Quit 
  Write !,"Valid Entry: ",val
  Quit
```

Comment: Thank you for responding back so quickly. This helps out tremendously and going forward I know what to do. You version of the code is much more readable. I have been learning this material from a programming reference guide from the course I am going to attend. They use short commands and dots in their material.

Comment: FYI. Dots are not standard Mumps and will only work on Cache.

Comment: I think you meant braces instead of dots.

Answer (score 0):

the  short commands are legacy from when original MUMPS code and source were limited to 4K bits of memory.

the dots under the IF or i  designate the steps for the given IF STATEMENT TO DO
more from the M or Cache language derivatives

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).